# Using dynamic to find a property

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a set of messages which I cannot alter their structure, but all of them follow the same property structure after you drill into the first two. For example,

```
public class Animal {
    public Dog Doggy { get; set; }
}

public class MixedAnimal {
    public CatDog CatDoggy { get; set; }
}

public class Dog {
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Age age { get; set; } 
}

public class CatDog {
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Age age { get; set; } 
}
```

If I have a structure like this: `SomeObj.Item` where `SomeObj` is some object and `Item` is of type `object` which can hold either an `Animal` or `MixedAnimal`. How would I get to the value of either `Dog` or `CatDog` using the keyword `dynamic`?

I can get the top level object using `SomeObj.Item as dynamic`, and then do:

`(SomeObj.Item as dynamic).Doggy.Name`

but what I want is to just get the name without knowing the type of `Item`.

`(SomeObj.Item as dynamic).(Something as dynamic).Name`

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the name of your `CatDog` property in `MixedAnimal`?

Comment: After you declare variable as dynamic, you don't need to cast to dynamic everything after dots. they are automatically dynamic too.

Comment: `dynamic` requires that the member exists, so it's not going to help you. If the object implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` and the returned meta-object implements `GetMemberNames`, that would give you what you want, but that won't be the case here. What you need is reflection.

Comment: or... try-catches!

Comment: @MattBurland Fixed. It's different then the property in `Animal`

Comment: @madreflection Could you give an example using reflection?

Comment: Can you not just say `if(SomeObj.Item is Animal)` and `if(SomeObj.Item is MixedAnimal)`? Or is it the case that you don't actually know all the possible types?

Comment: @Jimenemex: First see if you can use Matt's suggestion of doing a simple type test. Reflection is mad science, which is okay only if you can't use normal science.

Comment: @MattBurland You recommendation is what we currently have, but I still need to do that for every different type that we have. They are known types and I'm trying to avoid repeating that check for each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection is quite easy to resolve this problem. Something like this (general idea):

```cs
object animal = new Animal { Doggy = new Dog { age = 10, name = "Good boy" }};
var members = animal.GetType().GetMembers();

foreach (PropertyInfo member in members.Where(x => x is PropertyInfo))
{
    if (member.PropertyType.Name == "Dog" || member.PropertyType.Name == "CatDog")
    {
        var propertyValue = member.GetValue(animal);
        var propertyType = propertyValue.GetType();
        var nameMember = propertyType.GetProperty("name");
        var ageMember = propertyType.GetProperty("age");

        var nameValue = nameMember.GetValue(propertyValue);
        var ageValue = ageMember.GetValue(propertyValue);

        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {nameValue}, Age: {ageValue}");
    }
}
```

Everything you need to do additionally is providing list of type names which you want to process (like "Dog" or "CatDog" here).